# Iterate through a specific field (e.g. 5th,10th,15th,...) in an dynamic array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I want to iterate through an dynamic array (the array length changes all the time) and only extract the information on the 5th , 10th, 15th, ... field. How could I do that? My approach is something like below:

```
var counter = 4;

for (var i = 1; i < dataArray.length/5-1; i++) {
        var someInformation = dataArray[counter]

counter = counter + 5;
```

But I have problems with the array length. When using `data.Array.length` it iterates through the array too often. Using `data.Array.length/5` cuts off some information when the array length is uneven. And `data.Array.length/5-1` also loses information. How can I loop through my array without information loss and without iterating too often so that `someInformation` doesn't get null values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overthinking it a bit. :-)

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i += 5) {
    console.log(dataArray[i]);
}
```

*(Note that I started with 0, as that's the first entry in the array.)*

The `<` will ensure that even after `i += 5` goes well above the length, you don't try to access beyond the end of the array. For example:

```js
var dataArray = [
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
];
for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i += 5) {
    console.log(dataArray[i]);
}
```

That array has twelve entries. Even though after outputting the value 10 the `i += 5` ends up being 15, that's fine, because we don't enter the body of the loop, since `15 < 12` is false.

Comment: Wouldn't this break on the final iteration whenever the length of the array isn't equal to a multiple of 5? An array of length 6 will jump from i=5 to i=10 because 5<6

Comment: @millerbr But then `i >= dataArray.length` so the iteration won't proceed.

Comment: @millerbr: It won't "break," no. It will stop looping. See my note at the bottom of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Open the console to view the output.

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26];
var filtered = arr.filter(function(item, index){
  //array indexes start at 0 so add 1
  //this returns true if the number is divisible by 5
  return (index + 1) % 5 === 0;
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of:

```
                for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i += 5) {
              var someInformation = dataArray[i];
            }
```

The first item will always be 0 and i += 5 rather than i++ will add 5 each time you iterate through the **for loop**.  You will probably also want to declare someInformation outside your loop and use += rather than = which will then just hold the last value.

Good luck